# Ros2 change lifecycle node transition event topic name

Tags: ros2, remap, can

I am using the ros2 socket_can library from autoware and I have seen that I am not able to remap the /socket_can_receiver/transition_event
Is there a way to do it?

I have tried using the next launch file but I continue to have the /socket_can_receiver/transition_event topic when it should have been remapped to /another_name

````
def generate_launch_description():
    socket_can_receiver_node = LifecycleNode(
        package='ros2_socketcan',
        executable='socket_can_receiver_node_exe',
        name='socket_can_receiver',
        namespace=LaunchConfiguration('namespace'),
        parameters=[{
            'interface': LaunchConfiguration('interface'),
            'interval_sec':
            LaunchConfiguration('interval_sec'),
            'use_bus_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_bus_time'),
        }],
        remappings=[
                ('/socket_can_receiver/transition_event', '/another_name'),],
        output='screen')
return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('namespace', default_value=''),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('interface', default_value='can0'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('interval_sec', default_value='0.01'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('use_bus_time', default_value='false'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('auto_configure', default_value='true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('auto_activate', default_value='true'),
        socket_can_receiver_node,
    ])


```
````

Comment: Regardless if you can, you probably should not be remapping internal topics for lifecycle management.